# Dynamically change column sequence in Birt report

Tags: birt

I have birt report design with following columns:
Client Id,Client Name, Client Address, Client Mobile, Client Pan Num, Client Company, Client Salary 
Now i want to generate report based on user preference .

e.g. user1 wants report with following column sequence/order

Client Company,Client Name, Client Address, Client Mobile, Client Pan Num,Client Salary ,Client Id

user2 wants report with following column sequence/order
Client Name,Client Mobile,Client Company,Client Address, Client Id, Client Pan Num,  Client Salary

how to achieve above functionality in birt?